# OSB failing to process message that doesn't exist in queue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, soa, osb

My instance of OSB is attempting to process a message from a JMS queue that doesn't exist - I believe this has already been processed and removed, but my current concern is the multiple failures each second it is trying to continue. The error logs are now useless as they're flooded with failures for one particular message.

I have rebooted the managed servers and admin server, but each time, it is immediately reattempting to process the same message. I believe this is having knock-on effects to performance, and I have had to remove all logs as the file system is continuing to overflow.

Where is this "currently processing" message being picked up from, and how can I progress this so that it will not keep trying to reprocess this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, a problematic message is processing continuous failure within a JMS queue. There are 2 important actions.

1. Identify failure root cause. For me to help you with this item
   depends on the error message. If error details are provided, I might
   provide suggestions.
2. Protect environment by JMS Queue Configuration for Delivery Failure
   such as "Expiration Policy", "Redelivery Limit", "Error Destination"
   etc.

Please check following [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLACH/pagehelp/JMSjmsdestinationsjmsqueueredeliverytitle.html#:%7E:text=The%20error%20destination%20must%20be,undeliverable%20messages%20are%20simply%20deleted.) for these configurations.